# What is "Fourier Transformation induced Spectroscopy" really?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, definition, fourier-transform, spectroscopy

With regard to "Conventional and Advanced Characterization techniques", what is meant by, "Fourier Transformation Induced Spectroscopy "? A detailed answer to this is most welcome. It seems that someone is keen and eager to list this as a specified skill set on pen and paper. I am a asking everything from Material Science and Engineering background. A slight insight into this as a characterization technique is what is demanded for.

In short: **Is "Fourier Transformation Induced Spectroscopy" a method/technique in its own right?**

[Here is related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234976/247642), about the difference between a time-domain NMR and Fourier-transform NMR.

Comment: Do you have a paper or anything to reference? Almost all spectroscopy is based on some kind of transform whether it's Fourier or Inverse Scattering. At worst this is just redundant.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Not really can you give me the intuition behind the process?

Comment: There is so much context missing that I can't give you any kind of answer. What is this for? What is your background? Etc. Please edit these details into your post to make a question that meets this community's question quality standards.

Comment: It seems there is a couple of word missing. "The term Fourier-transform spectroscopy reflects the fact that in all these techniques, a Fourier transform is required to turn the raw data into the actual spectrum, and in many of the cases in optics involving interferometers,..." from Wikipedia.

Comment: It is important to stress that **Fourier-transform spectroscopy** is a name for a specific technique, even though Fourier transform is ubiquitous in spectroscopic applications. If you have never heard about this technique, do not hurry to close this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fourier-transform spectroscopy is not just any spectroscopy.** Fourier transform involves conversion from the time domain to the frequency domain and back, so it is necessarily present in all spectroscopic applications - whether the "conventional" spectroscopy or the Fourier-transform spectroscopy. However, in the "conventional" spectroscopy one studies spectra by irradiating the object with essentially monochromatic radiation. The spectrum is obtained by changing the frequency of the radiation used. In Fourier-transform spectroscopy one would typically use a single pulse (or a series of pulses) with a broad spectrum (e.g., linearly increasing in time) and then compare the output spectrum with the known spectrum of the pulse. This necessarily involves a deconvolution operation performed via Fourier transform, hence the name of the technique.

Judging by the comments one had already had idea to look into Wikipedia: [Fourier-transform spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier-transform_spectroscopy) and [Fourier-transform infrared spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier-transform_infrared_spectroscopy). I would recommend following the References section in both these articles for more specific information, since the technique is rather established and exist in many variations.